# CiviContribute & Paypal Business Account

Tags: civicontribute, paypal

I'm running Civicrm 4.7.0 on Wordpress and a paypal business account. I'm having problem configuring the payment processor with paypal. 1) is  not possible add paypal button in html, 2) configuring live and test parameters civicrm save test parameters same as on live 3) standard and pro paypal version not working. What's the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should setup Paypal in CiviCRM (via Admin > System Settings > Payment Processor ie at path civicrm/admin/paymentProcessor?reset=1) and then use Contribution pages with the paypal payment provider.

Comment: Problem solved and payment processor activated, but after the first test transaction nothing happens. When I try to pay a contribute the paypal page doesn't appear and the transition finish without a payment.